# JavaScript synchronous function

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've got the below bit of code:

```
ApiClient.prototype.UserLogin = function(data, callback){
    var url = baseURL+'users/login';
    var params = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    };

    function cb(success, response, code){
        if (success === 1){
            response = JSON.parse(response);
           // Save User ID & Username to App Properites to be used for Auth.
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("user_id", response.message._id);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("username", response.message.username);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("password", data.password);
            callback(response.success, response, code);
        } else {
            callback(success, response, code);
        }
    }

    this._request(url, params, cb);
};
```

I'm getting cases where the callback `callback(response.success, response, code)` is fired and the properties above have not been set.

Is it possible to make make the callback only fire one the properties have been set?

**Update to include how the function is called:**

```
api.UserLogin({
    'password' : password,
    'username' : username
    }, function(success, res, code) {
       if (success == 1) {
          // Do stuff..
```

Comment: What about the `else` clause which is called when "success" is not `1`?

Comment: All your code is synchronous so the problem should probably something else. Or does your `Properties.setString` method perform any kind of XHR?

Comment: Is `callback` meant to be passed into that function, or is it a global function?

Comment: @m90 - the `Ti.App.Properties.setString` simply sets application level variables

Comment: @Andy - I've updated the code above to include the full function

Comment: does setting the properties change the dom at all, like an html attrib? sometimes the dom gets behind. a short setTimeout usually fixes it.

Comment: @dandavis - It's not a web app, its a mobile application (http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/) but coded in javascript

Comment: Can you double check that you "get those cases" also when `success === 1` (as in @Pointy's comment)?

Comment: well, try a aetTimeout anyway, who knows how they coded setString...

Comment: @m90, @Pointy - I don't think it's the else clause that's causing the issue because the `callback(response.success, response, code);` also checks to make sure that `response.success` is 1.

The xhr call has an `xhr.onload` and an `xhr.onerror` function which also return `xhr.onerror = function(e) { callback(0,net, this.status, this); };` and    `xhr.onload = function() {
        callback(1,this.responseText, this.status);
    };`

Comment: Have you checked that your  `response.message._id` and other fields is always defined? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: why does onload fires calls with 1 always? by your code it seems like you are saying that onload always is successful but onload is only when you get an answer from your server. So maybe your request has failed (login) but you are assuming it has worked with callback(1,this.responseText, this.status)